# Pandas merge tables: only distinct Ids from second table

Tags: python, pandas, merge, concatenation

I am trying to figure out if it's possible to join/merge/concat two tables and just instead of 'outer' I'd like to pick the distinct Ids from the second table with the pandas built-in options.

Right now I am doing something along the lines and 
I have the feeling that my code is not very elegant:

```
a = [['a', '1.2', '4.2'], ['b', '70', '0.03'], ['c', '8', '1']]
b = [['a', '52', '49'], ['b', '23', '0.05'], ['x', '5', '0']]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['id_col', 'two', 'three'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(b, columns=['id_col', 'two', 'three'])


# remove df2 entries also in df1
different_ids = set(df2.id_col).difference(set(df1.id_col))
df2 = df2[df2.id_col.isin(different_ids)]
# merge data frames
df_merged = pd.concat([df1,df2])
```

the merged df should have the entries a,b,c from df1 and x from df2.

Comment: please post a reproducible example of inputs and desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `concat` `df1` and `df2` and then `drop_duplicates` on column `id_col`.

```
>>> df = pd.concat((df1, df2))
>>> print(df.drop_duplicates('id_col'))
  id_col  two three
0      a  1.2   4.2
1      b   70  0.03
2      c    8     1
2      x    5     0
```

Comment: See, I knew there must be a better solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do all that by subsetting `df2` with `id_col` which are not in `df1.id_col` with `isin` and then concat `df1` and resulted dataframe:

```
res = pd.concat([df1, df2[~df2.id_col.isin(df1.id_col)]])

In [186]: res
Out[186]:
  id_col  two three
0      a  1.2   4.2
1      b   70  0.03
2      c    8     1
2      x    5     0
```

**Timing:**

```
In [23]: %timeit pd.concat((df1, df2)).drop_duplicates('id_col')
100 loops, best of 3: 1.95 ms per loop

In [24]: %timeit pd.concat([df1, df2[~df2.id_col.isin(df1.id_col)]])
100 loops, best of 3: 1.79 ms per loop
```

From timing comparison this is faster..

Comment: This also works, thanks - but I am not a friend of the `df2[df2 blabla]` notation and therefore accepted Colins answer

Comment: @dmeu if you're interested in timing that's faster but I think @ Colin's solution is more readable though.

Comment: Good to know - but yes, my priority is always having legible code, so that the future me will understand it easily ;)